# Happy precedence function definition and variable

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

I have been struggling to remove all s/r conflicts from my parser today. I managed to remove all of them but a single one.

The syntax of my language should be haskell-like. And instead of a `main`, I have a top level expression which is the entry.

The parser is shown below. I have also added an excerpt from the `Parser.info` file that Happy generates in which it describes the shift/reduce conflicts.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that once the parser has encountered a `varname` for a function definition it can take two branches. It can either assume that there are more `varname`s to come because it is currently parsing a function definition (which has one or more parameters), or it can stop parsing it as a variable expression. The possible `varname` after that is then just another expression.

I have played around with `%prec` rules and nothing seemed to help.

My first reasoning was that, given that the parser wants to shift for a function definition, I can give that rule precedence. I also tried adding precedence to the `=` operator (for function definition) such that I could put it under the function definition's precedence but that did not work either.  My guess is that I don't fully understand how parsers work. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

A small side-note, the default behaviour - what I think is thus a shift - is the desired behaviour as well.

```
state 25 contains 1 shift/reduce conflicts.

...

State 25

    Definition -> varname . ':' ':' Type                (rule 7)
    Definition -> varname . FunctionParameters '=' Exp bl    (rule 8)
    Atom -> varname .                                   (rule 20)

    '('            reduce using rule 20
    '<'            reduce using rule 20
    '>'            reduce using rule 20
    '/'            reduce using rule 20
    '*'            reduce using rule 20
    '-'            reduce using rule 20
    '+'            reduce using rule 20
    "eq?"          reduce using rule 20
    number         reduce using rule 20
    ':'            shift, and enter state 27
    varname        shift, and enter state 28
            (reduce using rule 20)

    %eof           reduce using rule 20

    FunctionParametersgoto state 26
```

#### Parser

```
%nonassoc PARS
%nonassoc VAR
%%
Program
 : Definitions Exp { Program $1 $2 }
 | Exp             { Program [] $1 }


Definitions
 : Definitions Definition { ($1 ++ [$2]) }
 | Definition             { [$1]         }


Definition
 : type upsym '=' Type                   { TypeDef $2 $4  }
 | varname ':' ':' Type                  { FTypeDef $1 $4 }
 | varname FunctionParameters '=' Exp bl { FDef $1 $2 $4  }


FunctionParameters
 : FunctionParameters varname %prec PARS { $1 ++ [$2] }
 | varname                    { [$1]    }



Exp
 : let varname '=' Exp "in" Exp { Let $2 $4 $6  }
 | if Exp then Exp else Exp     { If $2 $4 $6   }
 | "Lam" varname "->" Exp       { Abs $2 $4     }
 | Form                         { $1            }


Form
 : Juxt { $1 }


Juxt
 : Juxt Atom { App $1 $2 }
 | Atom      { $1        }


Atom
 : '(' Exp ')'         { $2                }
 | number              { Value $ Number $1 }
 | varname %prec VAR   { Var $1            }
 | Binfs               { Value $ Binf $1   }


Binfs
 : "eq?"    { BinfEqual }
 | '/'      { BinfDiv   }
 | '*'      { BinfTimes }
 | '+'      { BinfPlus  }
 | '-'      { BinfMinus }
 | '>'      { BinfGT    }
 | '<'      { BinfLT    }
```

Comment: Precedences only have meaning when defined relative to some other things - you have defined a 'precedence' for one rule but not given an *actual* precedence to it with respect to some other rule.

Comment: I have done so as well. Seems like I forgot the copy/paste the relevant part there.